# Typescript Looks for Redis Types in wrong location inside Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, debugging, redis

My typescript compiler is looking in the wrong place for the types for one of my modules (redis), but only when run inside of Docker. Here's the end of the logging information running `tsc` inside the container:

```
======== Module name '../classes/range' was successfully resolved to '/app/node_modules/@types/semver/classes/range.d.ts' with Package ID '@types/semver/classes/range.d.ts@7.3.4'. ========

... more successful logs ...

node_modules/@types/connect-redis/index.d.ts(22,29): error TS2694: Namespace '"/app/redis"' has no exported member 'RedisClient'.
```

As you can see, it appears that the `tsc` command is looking inside of `/app/redis` for the member `RedisClient` rather than inside `/app/node_modules/@types/redis` which does export the type information. The `tsc` compiler doesn't have any problems when run from my local machine, only when it's being run inside the docker instance. Why is this the case?

Inside docker, the `tsc` command is being run from my `package.json` file, which is being run using docker-compose. The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: "typeorm-api:production"
    container_name: "typeorm-api"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    environment:
      ENV: production
      PORT: 1234
    env_file:
      - ".env.production"
    # This command will overwrite what is contained in the Dockerfile
    command: "npm run start:production"
    ports:
      - 1234:1234
    depends_on:
      - redis_server
  reverse:
    container_name: reverse
    hostname: reverse
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
  redis_server:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: redis_server
    volumes:
      - "./redis/production/data:/var/lib/redis"
    expose:
      - 6379
```

The `npm run start:production` command runs a command that's contained inside my `package.json` file (which installs my dependencies inside my application on the build step) and looks like this:

`"start:production": "tsc --extendedDiagnostics --traceResolution && node dist/index.js"`

The part that's failing is the `tsc` step and gives the error mentioned above.

The development settings work fine. Other files that might be useful in debugging, listed below.

1. Full `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapi",
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.16",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "@types/ioredis": "^4.22.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.2",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "ts-node": "9.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.28",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.21.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "connect-redis": "^5.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "ioredis": "^4.23.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "0.2.31",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:development": "ts-node-dev --respawn --poll src/index.ts",
    "start:production": "tsc --extendedDiagnostics --traceResolution && node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

2. Full Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.4.0-alpine3.10

# Specify that when you create the container, put the application inside the /app container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy our package.json + package-lock.json file into the /app folder (wildcard allows for package.lock.json)
COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm ci

# Copy source files + compilation configuration, db connection options, etc.
COPY ./src .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY ormconfig.js .
COPY modules.d.ts .

# This command will be overwritten to be start:production with our docker-compose.prod.yml file
CMD npm run start:development

EXPOSE 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so dumb.

I'd named a file that I was using in my project `redis.ts` and placed it in the root of my project. So, when the compiler was following it's normal rules to look for types, it looked at that file first, and didn't see the type declarations declared in it (because it wasn't the redis.d.ts file).

It didn't look inside the `node_modules` folder because of the name I chose. After changing the `redis.ts` file to `redisConfiguration.ts` everything works fine!